# Header tag doesnt auto adapt to mobile size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this problem, the header block does not auto adapt to screen size, that remains bigger than windows but i can't find the solution. I tried to give a `width:100%` to header with no results.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: I think you mean `<header>`...not *head*. Anyway...questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for this?

Comment: I think will require to use css3 media queries, here is reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: yep i meant header, anyway this is my snippet.

https://jsfiddle.net/r0rrv5mo/

Comment: Problem resolved, removing margin:left in mobile size

Answer (score 0):

From  what I have understood from your question, you could use     `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and download the require bootstrap packages.